# How can I don't repeat a part of code

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this code:

```
$(document)
.on(
  "click", 
  "#target", 
  function() { 
    //SOME_CODE
  }
);
```

And now I have to bind **`//SOME_CODE`** to another event after some specific code that will have to be executed only on this second event:

```
$(document)
.on(
  "click",
  "#anotherTarget",
  function() {
    //SOME_OTHER_CODE
    //SOME_CODE
  }
);
```

How can I call **`//SOME_CODE`** without copy-and-paste it and **without specify a function on top of both events**?

I've tried with this code:

```
$(document)
.on(
  "click.somecode", 
  "#target", 
  function() { 
    //SOME_CODE
  }
);

$(document)
.on(
  "click",
  "#anotherTarget",
  function() {
    //SOME_OTHER_CODE
    $(document).trigger("click.somecode");
  }
);
```

But the **`//SOME_CODE`** is not executed.

Comment: This is one of the specific reasons that functions exist.  If you don't want to use functions then you have to duplicate the code (copy/pasta).

Comment: Or use the trigger event function as suggested in other answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just fire a click event for the target?

```
$(document)
.on(
  "click",
  "#anotherTarget",
  function() {
    //SOME_OTHER_CODE
    $("#target").click();
  }
);
```

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
$("#target").trigger('click')
```

[see fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ME2Xj/)

Answer (score 0):

Put `//SOME_CODE` in a function, and call it. Example:

```
function doSomeCode() {
 //SOME_CODE
}

$(document)
.on(
  "click.somecode", 
  "#target", 
  doSomeCode
);

$(document)
.on(
  "click",
  "#anotherTarget",
  function() {
    //SOME_OTHER_CODE
    doSomeCode();
  }
);
```

Comment: *without specify a function on top of both events*

Comment: Then make a preprocessor that pastes it. If you want to unify code and still mantain extensibility, and keep side effects to a minimum, there is no other way. That's the use of functions!

Answer (score 0):

You can try like the following:

```
     $(document)
      .on(
        "click.somecode", 
        "#target", 
        function() { 
          console.log("SOME_CODE");
        }
      );

      $(document)
      .on(
        "click",
        "#anotherTarget",
        function() {
          console.log("SOME_OTHER_CODE");
          $("#target").trigger("click");
        }
      );
```

See the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/p7ULK/)

Comment: Thanks there was already other 2 answers with the same solution though